# I was wondering if this would be considered a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

Root node -----> node

So there is only one sub tree which only has one node. I was wondering if this would be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a valid binary tree: you can consider the root node as a node that has two childrens, one of which is null.

The non-null child is also considered to be a leaf (has both childrens set to null).

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. The reason why I am confused about binary trees is because i have just been introduced to it and i dont really understand the concept of it being an "ordered" tree.

Comment: @100 do not confuse BT (Binary Tree) with BST (Binary Search Tree). The latter is ordered and can be searched in logarithmic time - the former is not ordered!